# Qtableview split table view

Tags: python, pyqt

I finally figured out how to populate access and populate a Qtableview designed with QTDesigner.

The only problem I have is that the QT designer view and the actual application view differ (as shown in the in the pic below).
After import of my data, these views stay the same.
My data appears in the left field (with scroll adjuster) whilst the right field stays blank.

Does anybody know what setting may need to change in QTdesigner (or in my code) to resolve this?

Below also the .ui code

[image]

```
   <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>15</x>
      <y>160</y>
      <width>411</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
     <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="autoScrollMargin">
     <number>10</number>
    </property>
    <property name="editTriggers">
     <set>QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers</set>
    </property>
    <property name="showDropIndicator" stdset="0">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="textElideMode">
     <enum>Qt::ElideRight</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="showGrid">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="cornerButtonEnabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <attribute name="horizontalHeaderDefaultSectionSize">
     <number>70</number>
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
  </widget>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt use the tableview created by QTdesigner but added an new instant in my code, once I removed the creation of a new tableview window, and linked my data to the existing table, a single view was displayed